# Filtering by month using spinner in recyclerview in android studio firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

0

I'm using Android Studio and firebase as my database, I tried this and still unknown on what to do in this if condition, I just need what to put in if statement to filter the information I get by month. his is the app im trying to sort it by month, tried sort to january, BUT appointments from month 9 still shows up
[image: this is the database]
[image: this is the app]

```
public class adminAppoinment extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView drawerButton;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Bookings>bookingsList;
    List<ModelUser>modelUsers;
    AppointmentAdapter appointmentAdapter;
    Spinner months;
    String month;

    private ActivityAdminAppoinmentBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityAdminAppoinmentBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        NavigationView navigationView = (binding.navView);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_adminAppointment);

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (binding.drawerLayout);
        drawerButton = (binding.hamburger);

        drawerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        recyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication()));
        bookingsList = new ArrayList<>();
        modelUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        months = binding.spinner3;

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapterMonth = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.months, androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterMonth.setDropDownViewResource(androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        months.setAdapter(adapterMonth);
        months.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                month = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bookings").child("bookingDetails");
                Query query;
                //if january then 1, then filter by month 1 from database

                if (position == 1){
                     query = ref.child("bookingDetails").orderByChild("month").equalTo("January");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                getAllBooks();

            }
        });


        getAllBooks();

        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_adminAppointment);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), govethome2.class));
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        finishAfterTransition();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_adminUsers:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(),adminUsers.class));
                        finishAfterTransition();
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_adminAppointment:
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_adminOnlinePayment:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(),adminOnlinePayments.class));
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        finishAfterTransition();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_adminSettings:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(),adminSettings.class));
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        finishAfterTransition();
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    private void getAllBooks() {
        DatabaseReference mDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bookings");

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bookings").child("bookingDetails");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                bookingsList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Bookings bookings = ds.getValue(Bookings.class);
                    if(!bookings.getName().equals(firebaseUser.getDisplayName())){
                        bookingsList.add(bookings);
                    }

                    appointmentAdapter = new AppointmentAdapter(getApplication(), bookingsList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(appointmentAdapter);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Have you tried Frank's suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In your Firebase the value of your month is in integer but you are querying the month's name instead. Should you be passing position instead like

```
query = ref.orderByChild("month").equalTo(position);
```

Comment: Since the value of `month` is stored as a string, that should be `String.valueOf(position)`.

Comment: I tried both of your answers, it still outputs the appointments from month 9 when i choose January from the spinner.

Comment: Edited answer, remove the extra child() since you are already referencing it in `ref`.

Comment: Are there going to have changes in the getAllBooks(); codes below
because any condition I put on the if statements, when I run the app it still outputs all the appointments from month 9 even though I choose January from the spinner